# How to get ALL FB friends, not just the ones using my app?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8, facebook-friends

I am developing a WP8 app and I am trying to get a list of users friends. I am using the [FB SDK](http://facebooksdk.net/) for .NET . On developers.facebook.com in the Status & Review section of my app, I have this:

#### LOGIN PERMISSIONS

***email*** -
Provides access to the person's primary email address. This permission is approved by default.

***public_profile*** - Provides access to a person's basic information, including first name, last name, profile picture, gender and age range. This permission is approved by default.

***user_friends*** - Provides access to a person's list of friends **that also use your app**. This permission is approved by default.

The application I am developing gives me only one friend as an answer (the one that is also developing the app). My question is how do I get ALL the friends and not just the ones using the app? Which scope should I add?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869598/facebook-api-request-retrieves-only-2-friends

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

It seems this was intentional as a means to expose less data and give user's more privacy. There is a very detailed response here: [Get facebook friends with graph api v.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400204/get-facebook-friends-with-graph-api-v-2-0)