# Is there a way sign in on Android to facebook using graph api v 1.0 to facebook app made on graph api 2.0?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to get all user's friends in Android app via facebook graph api v 1.0. But unfortunately I have registered my app after April 30th 2014. [This post says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23416859) that request of "me/friends" graph api 1.0 does not work if you are signed in with graph api v 2.0. Is there a way to sign in with graph api v1.0 to app made on graph api 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple: no, there is not.

Before you ask a follow-up question: No, there really is no way to make Graph API V1.0 calls when you have a post-30 april app.

By the way, here is pretty good overview of all the changes with the new API:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading