# Which permissions I need to read Facebook App Users List

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I need list of users which are using my Facebook App. So I am sending below Request.

```
new Request( session, "/me/friends", null, HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
...});
```

Fo that which permissions I need to set in facebook app?

According to [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends) user_friends permission is required. But I cant find this permission anywhere in my app.

I was using "read_friendlists" permission but FB rejected it.

**Reply from Facebook Review team :**
read_friendlists 
Android
It looks like you're trying to use read_friendlists for something it cannot do. This permission doesn't show you a list of a person's friends.
Read_friendlists gives access to the names of custom lists a person has created to organize their friends. It will not help you invite a person's friends to use your app. To learn more about how to invite friends to an app, please see our FAQs.

Please remove "read_friendlists" from your submission. Learn more here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user_friends` permission is the right one to use. Keep in mind that `/me/friends` will only return the friends which are using the same app, not all friends.

See

- [Get facebook friends with Graph API v.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400204/get-facebook-friends-with-graph-api-v-2-0?rq=1)
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_friends