# How to get all my facebook friends with latest version of graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

I tried me/friends but it gives me only the app used friends. How to retrieve all my friends using the latest API

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get facebook friends with Graph API v.2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400204/get-facebook-friends-with-graph-api-v-2-0)

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, and has been asked here hundreds of times. Please use the search functionality of StackOverflow first before posting a question.

Have a look at

- [Get facebook friends with Graph API v.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400204/get-facebook-friends-with-graph-api-v-2-0?rq=1)

Comment: searching is not a thing anymore, you know :)