# How get list of friends and email using Facebook sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem i implement Facebook SDK in my view controller and want to get list of friends and email using Facebook. I wrote this:

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]];

loginView.delegate = self;
```

and then use the protocol method of FBLoginViewDelegate:

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user 
{
  self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.id;
  self.nameLabel.text = user.name;
  NSLog(@"%@", user);
  NSLog(@"%@", [user objectForKey:@"email"]);
}
```

In console i got this:

```
2014-12-04 14:56:48.746 FBLoginUIControlSample[2941:613] 

"first_name" = Pavel;
gender = male;
id = 1379600000000000;
"last_name" = name;
link = "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1379600000000000/";
locale = "ru_RU";
name = "Pavel name";
timezone = 2;
"updated_time" = "2014-12-03T11:47:13+0000";
verified = 1;

2014-12-04 14:56:48.748 FBLoginUIControlSample[2941:613] (null)
```

Comment: This is not possible, and never was. @ingrid's answer is correct.

Comment: @Tobi
I read this from here [link](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-facebook-login-sdk/)

Comment: There's nowhere said that you can get the email of friends. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Comment: @Tobi
I don't need the friends email. I need to get only my email and my list of friends. but z can't get this info. and i don't understand why...

Comment: Then this was a missunderstanding. You are aware that you can only get friends which use the same app? If there aren't any, you'll see none.

Comment: @Tobi
I only want when i login in my app in console i see all my friends from facebook

Comment: you can´t get ALL friends anymore. only those who authorized your app, as tobi said.

Comment: it's a pity thank everyone

Answer (score 2):

sorry , but you can't

Read `Facebook` [Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2)

you only can get the `email` when the user login , but you can't get user's `friends email`.

i am not really sure but maybe you can use "friendsusername"@facebook.com ("facebook email").

i found this, https://www.facebook.com/help/224049364288051

the person has to active @facebook option.

Comment: No, you can't get the "Facebook email"

Answer (score 0):

For friends with `Facebook SDK 3.0` you can do this

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                  NSDictionary* result,
                                  NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
        NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);
    }
}];
```

You can not access to any users email, excepts of yours.
Because FBGraphUser doesn't have an email @property, we can't access the information like with the name (dot-syntax), however the NSDictionary still has the email kv-pair and we can access it like we would do with a normal NSDictionary. 
With this method you can access to your email.

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             self.nameLabel.text = user.name;
             self.emailLabel.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: That's not gonna work. Friends permissions have been dismissed with the v2.0 Graph API, and getting the email addresses of friends was **never** possible, even with v1.0

Comment: Of friends no, but he need to get user email

Answer (score -2):

hope this will help you

you can get your friend list by using below code in your `viewDidLoad`

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/taggable_friends"
                                 parameters:nil
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {

                          }];
```

and some [info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23416859/3767017)

**EDIT**

the above answer only mention for friendlist not email(as its already quite clear by above answers) , now what you want friendlist

A friend list(Friend List V 2.2) - an object which refers to a grouping of friends created by someone or generated automatically for someone (such as the "Close Friends" or "Acquaintances" lists)

`from v2.0 you'll only be able to get all friends via the /me/taggable_friends` (see it by `result`)

Comment: This will only return friends who also use the app you are using. Plus, you don't get their email addresses.

Comment: ...also, this is only for tagging friends, you are not allowed to use it for anything else.

Comment: Please how can I use this in the 4.7 version? What is its equivalence?