# Fetch friends birthday using facebook graph api v2.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In v1.0, it was possible to ask for permissions that would allow an app to see a limited amount of friend data, such as a person's friend's likes, their birthdays, and so on.

In v2.0, those permissions have all been removed. It's no longer possible for an app to see data from a person's friends unless those friends have also logged into the app and granted permission for the app to see it that data.

Now the issue is that how we can get the friends birthday.I am using  user_friends permission that is providing me list of friends with their id, first name,middle name,gender but not birth day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible to gather friends birthdays with Graph API >=v2.0 anymore, because all `friends_*` permissions have been removed.

See:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

And, in case you want to ask, there's NO workaround for this.

Comment: Tobi can you please clarify one thing, if a user is using my app and one of his friend is also using my app then when I request friends birthday using graph api, will I at least be able to get 1 birthday result returned?

Comment: Never mind, I got my answer. For anyone else who stumbles along on this post, please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400204/get-facebook-friends-with-graph-api-v-2-0

Answer (score 3):

This is not an issue first of all. Facebook has change their policy. From now on Facebook will only provide

- user_email
- public profile
- Friend List (only friends using the app)

If you want information other than that then you need to ask permission from Facebook. also where you want all data and for which purpose that you need to tell them. Also you must have to upload your app for review process. If your app found proper then they will allow you.

for more Detail read this. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/

Comment: you don´t have to go through the review process with EVERY app. and the question was about getting the birthday of friends, not about getting data from the authorized user.