# Facebook Api getting total count of friends, but not friends data

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I am using Facebook API javascript SDK, and trying to get logged in user friends data
Here is the scope i am using

```
    FB.login(function(response) {
          statusChangeCallback(response);
          }, {
            scope:'publish_actions,user_friends,public_profile',
            return_scopes: true
    });

 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    $textInput = document.getElementById("searchText");

        var request =  jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/logged/ajax/facebook",
                        data: response });
        request.done(function( $data ) {
            jQuery(".loadingContent").css( "display", "none" );
            if($data == "success"){
               FB.api('/me/friends', function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
                });
            } else {
                alert($data);
            }
        });
         request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {

         });
});
```

but it returns me

```
({"data":[],"summary":{"total_count":79}})
```

data is always empty, though i am getting total count of my facebook friends

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Answer (score 7):

Since v2.0, you can only get friends who authorized your App too.

Check out the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

This question is also answered in several other threads already:

- [Get facebook friends with Graph API v.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400204/get-facebook-friends-with-graph-api-v-2-0)
- [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)
- [Get ALL User Friends Using Facebook Graph API - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850807/get-all-user-friends-using-facebook-graph-api-android)

Comment: why the downvote? please comment if you downvote, i am happy to fix errors or improve my answer, but it is definitely correct.

Comment: @luschn People be hatin'

Comment: Thank you @luschn, so
    ({"data":[],"summary":{"total_count":79}})
means the facebook account has 79 friends, but none of them [installed & authorized] the app?

Comment: exactly, that´s what it means. "authorized with the user_friends permission", to be specific.