# iOS/objective-c: Facebook integration importing contacts no longer possible?

Tags: ios, facebook, import, contacts

I am following a tutorial for integrating Facebook in an app.  However, it seems that when Facebook upgraded to V2.0 of their graph, they stopped allowing imports of contacts unless the contact has the App installed.

Does anyone know if there is any workaround to this? The [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u) available as described in these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400204/get-facebook-friends-with-graph-api-v-2-0) a year ago all seemed essentially inadequate for a commercial app.  But wondering if there have been any changes in the status quo so that you can import Facebook contacts.

(Facebook remains super aggressive itself about getting contacts from iPhone, google, etc.)

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: No there is no way to get facebook friends.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the Facebook SDK Graph API for getting contacts .

[Graph API Friends List](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, nothing has changed: you still can get only the contacts that are using your app AND that gave to your app the `user_friends` permission.

Please see this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u) with more details.